# Backbone js and populating a model with data using fetch()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I'm working in Backbone js and I am trying to populate a model with data using fetch. The problem is that the fetch appears to be working but my model is not populating with data.

A snippet of the code:

```
Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;
    Backbone.emulateJSON = true;

    ComponentsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        initialize : function() {

        },
        defaults : {
            component_id : null
        },
        urlRoot : "/components/ajax_component",

    });

    ComponentsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : $('body'),

        events : {
            'change #component-selector' : 'changeComponent',
        },

        initialize : function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'changeComponent');
            this.render();
        },

        changeComponent : function(e) {
            var clickedEl = $(e.currentTarget);
            var value = clickedEl.attr("value");
            var component = new ComponentsModel({id :value, component_id :value });
            component.fetch();
            component.toJSON();
            alert(component.get('component_name'));

        },

        render : function() {

        },
    });
```

And the JSON being return from the server looks like this:

```
{"component_id":"1","component_name":"Test Component 1","component_description":"A simple test component","component_required":"","user_id":"1","component_approved":"0","component_price":"0","component_overview":"'"}
```

The alert is always undefined. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fetch is async, that's why it has `success` and `error` callbacks. So it's no sure that the data are fetched by the time you try to get the property.
Try this:

```
component.fetch({
   success: function(){
       // Now you got your data
   }});
```