# Backbone js not populating a model with data using fetch()

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am using Backbone.js and trying to populate my model using fetch(). The problem I am having is that the returned data is not populating my model. I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768595/backbone-js-and-populating-a-model-with-data-using-fetch). The difference is that inside of my success function I am not seeing any data changes nor is a 'change' event being fired.

The code:

**Model**

```
window.Company = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "/api/company",
    defaults:{
        "id":null,
        "name":"",
        "address":"",
        "city":"",
        "state":"",
        "phone":""
    },
    events: {
        'change': 'doChange'
    },

    doChange: function(event) {
        alert('company changed');
    }
})
```

**The Router**

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes:{
        "":"home",
        "company/:id":"companyDetails"
    },

    initialize:function () {
        var user = new User();
        this.headerView = new HeaderView({
            model: user
        });
        $('.header').html(this.headerView.el);
        console.log("router initialized.");
    },

    companyDetails: function (id) {
        var company = new Company({
            id: id
        });
        company.fetch({
            success: function(){
                console.log('company.id is ' + company.id);
                console.log('company.name is ' + company.name);
                console.log('company.address is ' + company.address);
                $("#content").html(new CompanyView({
                    model: company
                }).el);
            }
        });
}


});
```

**JSON**

```
{"address":"555 Main St","name":"Confused Technologies","id":"8dc206cc-1524-4623-a6cd-97c185a76392","state":"CO","city":"Denver","zip":"80206","phone":"5551212"}
```

The name and address are always undefined. I have to be overlooking something simple???

**Edit**

Including the view that erroneously left out passing the model to the template.

**View**

```
window.CompanyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize:function () {
        this.render();
        console.log('CompanyView initialized');
    },

    render:function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        return this;
    }

})
```

Comment: What does `company.get('name')` or `company.toJSON()` say inside the success callback?

Comment: `company.get('name')` seems to return the name! `toJSON()` returns `[object Object]`. This is promising! What started all of this is in my underscore template I have `<%= name =>` and `<%= address %>` that were and still are empty. Any thoughts?

Comment: You usually call the template function as `html = template(this.model.toJSON())`, how are you doing it?

Comment: That was part of the problem. I will edit the original post to include my view. I was doing `$(this.el).html(this.template());`. When I changed it to `$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));` after updating my success callback to include the data parameter I got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attributes are not stored directly on the model.  They are stored in an [attributes hash](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes), so you would access them through `company.attributes`, though `company.get(attribute)` is the way it's usually done.  Along the same lines, you would pass `company.toJSON()` to your template function, as that returns a cloned hash of the model's attributes.

As for your change event not firing, I assume you mean the `change: doChange` in the model's events hash. Backbone Models do not actually do anything with an events hash. That's for delegating DOM events on Backbone Views. I bet if you put `company.on("change", function (model) { console.log(model.toJSON()); })` before your fetch call and removed the success callback, you'd see your model in the console.

Also, I don't think your `$("#content").html...` line is going to work like you expect. I'd rewrite your router callback like this:

```
companyDetails: function (id) {
  var company = new CompanyView({
    el: "#content", 
    model: new Company({ id: id })
  });

  // This line would be better in your view's initialize, replacing company with this.
  company.listenTo(company.model, "change", company.render);

  company.model.fetch();
}
```

CompanyView#render would typically pass `this.model.toJSON()` to a template function that returns html, and pass that to `this.$el.html()`.  So something like `this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));`

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful. the `company.on("change", function (model) { console.log(model.toJSON()); })` led me to change my success callback to include the data parameter.

Comment: So this coupled with my view changes I updated earlier (actually passing `this.model.toJSON()` to the template) did the trick. I am still a little fuzzy about the events hash but I am sure given a bit of time using backbone I will get it.

Comment: Also +1 for the passing the el into the constructor. It more clearly did what I was trying to do with  `$("#content").html...`.

Comment: Backbone won't do anything with an events hash on a model. You declare event handlers for model events with `.on` or `.listenTo`. That's usually preferred to a success callback, because models can change outside of a fetch call. The events hash is found on Backbone Views, for delegating DOM events like `click` to handler methods on the View.

Answer (score 0):

OK. The problem with not updating my model was as far as I can tell an async issue. I updated the success callback to include the data parameter like so:

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#content').html(new CompanyView({
        model: data
    }).el);
}
```

Note that I am not passing the company object as the model rather the raw returned data. This solved my model problem.

I mentioned in a comment that this started with my underscore template variables `<%= name %>' etc... being empty. I changed my view to this:

```
window.CompanyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize:function () {
        this.render();
        console.log('CompanyView initialized');
    },

    render:function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }

})
```

Those to things got both my model updated and variables propagating to the template.

Comment: That doesn't seem like it should work.  How does `this.model.toJSON()` get called when you're not passing a model to your View? The 'raw data' object won't have a toJSON method. When is render called?

Comment: It works. I am new to backbone.js but, I believe that assigning the model `model:data` does some sort of transformation to a `Backbone.Model` object. `render()` is called in the views `initialize` function.

Comment: Edited the post to include the full view rather than just the render function.

Comment: Ah, Backbone.Model's fetch calls the success function you passed in with the model, after the attributes have been set.  So your `data` variable in the success function is actually the model.  The actual response is the second argument in the success function.  source: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-55

Comment: Aha.. so it is not actually the raw data. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Interestingly enough now the original success function works. Guessing that i had too many problems at once E.G. not passing the mode to the view. Marking your original answer as the answer. Thanks!